# Large image should ocupy all page without blank space around

Tags: spacing, graphics, r

I'm new to LaTeX and although my supervisor does not use LaTeX, I've decided to do my master thesis in LaTeX.

However, I'm having a problem with the images. I have big images generated through R. They have some white space around but I manually removed the white space. Nevertheless, I've tried a lot of different examples found in the Internet and none resolve the issue. To better understand the problem, I attach a print screen of the image in the middle of the page.
[image]

The image is quite large itself but I think that if I was able to put max width of the page, one will be able to see the picture. Here is the picture alone
[image]

The code used is the following:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}{\textheigth}]{../Files/PMM/densityplotVac.png}
%\includegraphics[width=1.2 \textwidth ,keepaspectratio]{../Files/PMM/densityplotVac.png}       
\end{figure}
```

If any one was any pointer, I would be very grateful. Thank you very much

Comment: +1 for *although my supervisor does not use LaTeX, I've decided to do my master thesis in LaTeX*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the float-package for positioning the image.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[H]
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.png}
 \caption{Kernel density estimates ...}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It worked! It seems so simple and I wasn't able to figure it out. Before the [H] I had [h!]. So the main issue was the lack of the package float?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the width of the image to the `\textwidth`, which is the width of the area with text in it:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../Files/PMM/densityplotVac.png}       
\end{figure}
```

The trick is in setting the actual width of the image rather than the maximum size.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I also added the package float like suggested in the other comment